# Usage of scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp for Integer design variable

Tags: optimization, scipy

I'm trying to use the scipy.optimize.slsqp for an industrial-related constrained optimization. A highly non-linear FE model is used to generate the objective and the constraint functions, and their derivatives/sensitivities.

The objective function is in the form:
**obj=a number calculated from the FE model**

A series of constraint functions are set, and most of them are in the form:
**cons = real number i - real number j (calculated from the FE model)**

I would like to try to restrict the design variables to integers as that would be what input into the plant machine.

Another consideration is to have a log file recording what design variable have been tried. if a set of design variable (integer) is already tried for, skip the calculation, perturb the design variable and try again. By limiting the design variable to integers, we are able to limit the number of trials (while leaving the design variable to real, a change in the e.g. 8th decimal point could be regarded as untried values).

I'm using SLSQP as it is one of the SQP method (please correct me if I am wrong), and the it is said to be powerful to deal with nonlinear problems. I understand the SLSQP algorithm is a gradient-based optimizer and there is no way I can implement the restriction of the design variables being integer in the algorithm coded in FORTRAN. So instead, I modified the slsqp.py file to the following (where it calls the python extension built from the FORTRAN algorithm):

```
slsqp(m, meq, x, xl, xu, fx, c, g, a, acc, majiter, mode, w, jw)
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i]=int(x[i])
```

The code stops at the 2nd iteration and output the following:

***Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)

           Current function value: -1.286621577077517

            Iterations: 7

            Function evaluations: 0

            Gradient evaluations: 0***

However, one of the constraint function is violated (value at about -5.2, while the default convergence criterion of the optimization code = 10^-6).

Questions:
1. Since the FE model is highly nonlinear, I think it's safe to assume the objective and constraint functions will be highly nonlinear too (regardless of their mathematical form). Is that correct?
2. Based on the convergence criterion of the slsqp algorithm(please see below), one of which requires the sum of all constraint violations(absolute values) to be less than a very small value (10^-6), how could the optimization exit with successful termination message?

```
 IF ((ABS(f-f0).LT.acc .OR. dnrm2_(n,s,1).LT.acc).AND. h3.LT.acc)
```

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any relevant modification in that link and it seems there is additional text/images missing from your post. No matter what you do, you will never be able to modify SLSQP to incorporate integers (without creating a completely new algorithm). Post-processing like rounding of course is possible but that's not what you want (i don't know exactly because your post is so incomplete). Why not using the right tools for the task? Mixed-Integer QCQP + some convexifications if needed? (automatically done in Couenne; but it's surely not really large-scale).

Comment: I would recommend to look for an MINLP solver instead.